# Variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, messaging

I'm improving an existing messaging system for my project, which should accept a variable number of parameters. Right now generics are used to pass arguments to the system. A lot of code repeats itself, so the question is - is it possible to merge all the versions of the class that take different number of parameters into a one single class?
The whole messaging system I take as a foundation for mine can be found here: [CSharpMessenger](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=CSharpMessenger)

Code excerpts:

```
public delegate void Callback();
public delegate void Callback<T>(T arg1);
public delegate void Callback<T, U>(T arg1, U arg2);
```

Version with no parameters:

```
static public class Messenger
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    static public void AddListener(string eventType, Callback handler)
    {
        if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
            eventTable.Add(eventType, null);
        }
        // Add the handler to the event.
        eventTable[eventType] = (Callback)eventTable[eventType] + handler;
    }

    static public void Invoke(string eventType)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d))
        {
            Callback callback = (Callback) d;
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version with one parameter:

```
static public class Messenger<T>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    static public void AddListener(string eventType, Callback<T> handler)
    {
        if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
            eventTable.Add(eventType, null);
        }
        // Add the handler to the event.
        eventTable[eventType] = (Callback<T>)eventTable[eventType] + handler;
    }

    static public void Invoke(string eventType, T arg1)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d))
        {
            Callback<T> callback = (Callback<T>) d;
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(arg1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version with two parameters:

```
static public class Messenger<T, U>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    static public void AddListener(string eventType, Callback<T, U> handler)
    {
        if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
            eventTable.Add(eventType, null);
        }
        // Add the handler to the event.
        eventTable[eventType] = (Callback<T, U>)eventTable[eventType] + handler;
    }

    static public void Invoke(string eventType, T arg1, U arg2)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d))
        {
            Callback<T, U> callback = (Callback<T, U>) d;
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(arg1, arg2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see most of the code repeats itself, Is it possible to create some general version of the same class, that will take a variable number of parameters and to avoid repeating the same code so many times?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't the invocations on the generic classes missing the callback parameters?

Comment: you are not passing any parameters to the callback?

Comment: @Jordão Yes, you're right. I was in a hurry when I was removing all the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback parameters are normally passed in a subclass of `EventArgs`. There's already a simple  generic delegate that abstracts this: `EventHandler<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs`. The variability in parameters can be added to subclasses of `EventArgs`.

So, if you can restructure your code to use these classes, you can have just one version. Something like this:

```
public static class Messenger<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs {
  private static Dictionary<string, EventHandler<TEventArgs>> eventTable = 
    new Dictionary<string, EventHandler<TEventArgs>>();

  public static void AddListener(string eventType, EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler) {
    if (eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType)) {
      eventTable[eventType] = eventTable[eventType] + handler;
    }
    else {
      eventTable.Add(eventType, handler);
    }
  }

  public static void Invoke(string eventType, TEventArgs args) {
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> d;
    if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d)) {
      if (d != null) {
        d(args);
      }
    }
  }
}
```